# How can I force the app to increase the Media sound and not the call sound

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have noticed that in apps like Waze, when I increase the volume using the physical button, it increases the Media. But in other apps, and so like mine, it increases the call volume.

Is this possible in iOS as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch {
        print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
    }
    // Other project setup
    return true
}
```

This will make your app behave like a media app.